# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: freebsd, php5, lighttpd

I have tried to run my script via cron, but it was not working...

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /usr/local/www/maintain.php > /usr/local/www/php.log
```

So I decided to try to run this script from the command line in putty like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /usr/local/www/maintain.php > /usr/local/www/php.log
```

And then I've received the following warning/error message:

```
# /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/www/maintain.php > /usr/local/www/php.log
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/libpcre.so' - Cannot open &quot;/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/libpcre.so&quot; in Unknown on line 0
```

But this script is running great, when I'm running it via www like `http://my-url.com/maintain.php`.

I'm using PHP 5~ with Lighttpd running od FreeBSD. Where is my problem?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/libpcre.so` exist? Are you sure it's running from lighttpd and you don't just have error display off?

Comment: It does exist, but in `/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so`.

Comment: When I create a symlink in `/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/` it does print another message: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'libpcre.so' in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: Nothing more than the file is required, try copying it instead. Alternatively update the reference in the file in `/etc/php.d/X.ini`, or it may be in your master `php.ini`

Comment: Look for `grep -r libpcre /usr/local/etc/php*` and remove it.

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz I dont know if thats a good idea to remove it... It doesnt fix the problem...

Comment: Chances are your php cli is not loading your php.ini by default have you tried:

/usr/local/bin/php **-c /path/to/you/php.ini** -f /usr/local/www/maintain.php > /usr/local/www/php.log

Comment: @Oneiroi Its kinda funny, because I've compilled my PHP using the FreeBSD's ports, months ago, PHP and everything related with that works fine with lighttpd - BUT I can't locate my `php.ini` file, it seems like its doesn't exist, and never existed at all... how is that possible? `O_o`

Comment: @Cyclone this may be of some help in locating the file even if it not named php.ini: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/custom-phpini-file-for-each-domain-user.html

Comment: @Oneiroi I dont use that way of loading the ini file..., there is nothing related to the php.ini in my lighttpd.conf file.

Comment: Don't symlink libpcre into /usr/local/lib/php. It's not needed. Please edit your question with the output of `ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache22/libphp5.so`. Also others are right that you may need to fix `php.ini` as by default the port doesn't install it, but two versions with `-development` and `-production` suffixes.

Comment: I'm using lighttpd for the web server (earlier was nginx). I'll try to fix my php.ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command (replacing /usr/bin/php with the path you're using to the PHP binary, in this case, /usr/local/bin/php):

```
# ldd /usr/bin/php
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00932000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00f16000)
libedit.so.0 => /usr/lib/libedit.so.0 (0x008dd000)
libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00791000)
libgmp.so.3 => /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3 (0x00de8000)
...
```

It allows you see precisely what shared libraries the binary depends on. I had this problem a while back with some cryptographic PHP library. The errors from PHP provided no useful information about why the script wasn't running, until I ran this command and could see what was missing. Whilst the error you are seeing complains about one specific library, there is a good chance that library depends on yet another one, which PHP is not telling you about in the error. ldd gives you this vital missing information.

Note I am running CentOS Linux here. For BSD, the ldd command might be called something else (I have never used BSD so can't comment on that).

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so` is the C library.

Did you compile php yourself or from ports?

It looks like it was compiled with a custom PCRE library, because normally php should include pcre support.

Comment: From ports, php does include this library by default, while using lighttpd everything is fine, but when I run a PHP script from a command line, it throws this error...

Comment: Shouldnt it be a comment?

Comment: yes, but on that day i didn't have the privilege to add comments :). lighttpd uses php-cgi, since you are not reading any variables, you might try to use php-cgi from the commandline

Comment: I already did `:/`. Throws the same as normal `php`.

Comment: FreeBSD ports don't install a php.ini per default. Some examples are installed as /usr/local/etc/php.ini-development and -production. Do you by chance have the php5-pcre port installed? it was deleted when php was updated to 5.3.2. See /usr/ports/UPDATING 20100409 entry

Comment: I dont think it was installed.